# kafka connect could not be established to the kafka broker

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am using mac and install zookeeper and kafka through

```
brew install confluent-platform
```

By using the following commands,

```
zookeeper-server-start /usr/local/etc/kafka/zookeeper.properties
kafka-server-start /usr/local/etc/kafka/server.properties
connect-distributed /usr/local/etc/kafka/connect-distributed.properties
```

however connector shows the following messages such as

```
[2020-08-05 09:53:40,222] WARN [Producer clientId=inventory-connector2-dbhistory] Connection to node -1 (kafka/223.82.248.117:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:756)
[2020-08-05 09:53:40,230] WARN [Producer clientId=inventory-connector2-dbhistory] Bootstrap broker kafka:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:1024)
[2020-08-05 09:53:40,427] WARN [Producer clientId=inventory-connector-dbhistory] Connection to node -1 (kafka/223.82.248.117:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:756)
```

I started the kafka broker in the localhost, but as the message shows the broker 's address is 223.82.248.117:9092.

how would I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to set `advertised.listeners` in `server.properties` to be `localhost:9092`

Then `bootstrap.servers` in `connect-*.properties` to point there as well