# Can not connect to the Kafka broker from a Kafka consumer pod in the same namespace

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

**Problem**

I am trying to connect to a Kafka pod from a different Kafka consumer pod in the same namespace but the consumer can't connect to the broker.

I am seeing this error in the consumer pod logs

```
[2024-02-28 16:51:02,193] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-81790-1, groupId=console-consumer-81790] Connection to node 0 (localhost/127.0.0.1:19092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2024-02-28 16:51:03,098] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-81790-1, groupId=console-consumer-81790] Connection to node 0 (localhost/127.0.0.1:19092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

**My Questions**

What am I missing in the K8s config?
Any pointers to troubleshoot? I have shared multiple things that I have tried below.

**Context**

My Kafka yaml file

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: kafka
  labels:
    app: kafka
    service: kafka
  namespace: datastores
spec:
  containers:
    - image: xxx.xxx.xx/images/kafka:latest
      name: kafka
      ports:
        - containerPort: 19092
      environment:
        # These are some failed trial attempts to get the kafka pod to listen on localhost
        - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS
          value: PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:19092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:19092,CONNECTIONS_FROM_HOST://localhost:19092
        - name: KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP
          value: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,CONNECTIONS_FROM_HOST:PLAINTEXT

      resources: {}
  restartPolicy: Always
status: {}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: kafka
    service: kafka
  name: kafka
  namespace: datastores
spec:
  ports:
    - name: "19092"
      port: 19092
      targetPort: 19092
  selector:
    app: kafka
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

My kafka-consumer yaml file

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: kafka-consumer-test
  labels:
    app: kafka-consumer-test
  namespace: datastores
spec:
  containers:
  - name: kafka-consumer
    image: xxx.xxx.xx/images/kafka:latest
    command: ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
    args:
      - |
        kafka-console-consumer.sh \
          --bootstrap-server localhost:19092 \
          --topic my-test-topic \
          --from-beginning
  restartPolicy: Never
```

**What I have tried so far**

1. Setting `listeners=PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092` in `server.properties` as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52726054/5355272).
2. Tried using these values for `--bootstrap-server kafka.datastores.svc.cluster.local:19092` or `--bootstrap-server kafka:19092`
3. set `advertised.listeners` as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63269666/5355272). You can see the alternative option to set this via the config in the yaml file

Lemme know if any additional information is required.
TIA!

Comment: Everything you've shown is having the containers connect to themselves, not external services. All answers you've linked are from **outside** the cluster. I suggest not creating resources manually. See https://strimzi.io/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried using `--bootstrap-server kafka.datastores.svc.cluster.local:19092` but still didn't work to connect to the Kafka cluster from another pod. Am I missing something?

The reason to create resources manually is because in our local testing environment, a `kind k8s cluster` exists and we create small pods for different services to run. `kafka` already exists and I'm just trying to add a new consumer to consume from that `kafka` pod and trying to find how to do it.

Comment: `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS` doesn't expose a service by that name, so clients will be unable to connect. An operator, or a Helm chart will set that correctly, even in kind cluster